# Performance: do everything at once, or loop several times for each operation?

Tags: c++, performance, caching

Is it **typically** faster (and why) to perform all instructions at once, while iterating? This seems necessary for cache reasons.  Or can we iterate several times?

One thing to note is that `count` is large (1000 to 1 000 000).

```
//original loop, wish to separate into several loops:
for(size_t i=0; i<10000000; ++i){
    floatVec_A[i] +=  floatVec_B[i] - floatVec_C[i]*floatVec_D[i];
    floatVec_A[i] = std::sin(floatVec_A[i]);
    //and so on
}
```

vs what I wish (but afraid it might be a slow approach **...usually**?):

```
for(size_t i=0; i<10000000; ++i){
    floatVec_A[i] +=  floatVec_B[i];
}
for(size_t i=0; i<10000000; ++i){
    floatVec_A[i] += -floatVec_C[i]*floatvec_D[i];
}
for(size_t i=0; i<10000000; ++i){
    floatVec_A[i] = sin(floatVec_A[i]);
}
//and so on
```

I wish it because these separate loops could then be replaced by the neat-looking functions, making code much readable. For me it would make life a lot easier, since internally I am actually using AVX intrinsics, and the code above is simplified for example's sake.

```
myMath::add_toFirst( floatVec_A,  floatVec_B); 
myMath::mul_toThird( floatVec_C,  floatVec_D,  resultVec);
myMath::add_toFirst( floatVec_A,  resultVec);
myMath::sin(floatVec_A);
//and so on
```

**In general**, does the perfromance suffer in the latter scenario, by little or by a lot, and because of which factors?

Comment: `does the perfromance suffer in the latter scenario, by little or by a lot` What did your benchmarks say? ;-)

Comment: I wish to get a _general_ idea of what's more performant, and why. Especially if each iteration contains a lot of instructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example...

```
//original loop, wish to separate into several loops:
for(size_t i=0; i<10000000; ++i){
    floatVec_A[i] +=  floatVec_B[i] - floatVec_C[i]*floatVec_D[i];
    floatVec_A[i] = std::sin(floatVec_A[i]);
    //and so on
}
```

will perform best because of cpu cache.

Fetching data generally dominates performance and the first example is the most cache friendly (linear and predictable).  The compiler may actually join your loops into one loop for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

What is your typical pattern of accessing this vectors?
Do you iterate over them in parallel (like in your example) or do you often work with individual vectors?
In the first case, you may want to consider having a vector of structures of four float values. Then all four of them will be close to each other that makes them more cache-friendly.

Comment: Thanks! I would argue that since it's a vector of floats they are already close to each other, regardless of being grouped in structs or not. As far as I know, a chunk of nearby floats is fetched into the cache, even if I merely access an `[i]` index.

Comment: @Kari - Oh, I meant that your `floatVec_A[i]`, `floatVec_B[i]`, `floatVec_C[i]` and `floatVec_D[i]` are next to each other. Otherwise accessing four vectors at the same offset will NOT help your cache...